# copy elision of return values and noexcept

Tags: c++, exception, optimization, noexcept

I have a function template like this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto myfunc() noexcept
{
    return T{};
}
```

Is this function template guaranteed to be noexcept because of copy elision? If an exception is thrown inside the constructor, does this happen inside or outside the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that copy elision does is eliminate the actual copy or move. Everything happens "as-if" things happen without the copy-elision taking place (except for the copy itself, of course).

The construction occurs inside the function. Copy elision does not change that. All it does is eliminate the actual copy/move from taking place (am I repeating myself?) as the result of the function's return value getting shoved back into its caller.

So, if the class's ***default*** constructor throws an exception, the `noexcept` nukes the whole thing from high orbit.

If the copy/move constructor throws an exception, since the copy/move does not happen, everything continues to chug along.

With gcc 7.3.1, compiled using -std=c++17:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto myfunc() noexcept
{
    return T{};
}

class xx {
public:

    xx() { throw "Foo"; }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        myfunc<xx>();
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

The result:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
```

Now, let's mix it up, and throw an exception in both copy and move constructors:

```
class xx {
public:

    xx() { }

    xx(xx &&) { throw "Foo"; }

    xx(const xx &) { throw "Baz"; }
};
```

This runs without an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the return value occurs in the context of the callee (the function that contains the `return` statement). That is, if you want to leave open the possibility of handling an exception that is thrown by the default constructor of `T`, you should *not* declare `myfunc` with `noexcept`.

I understand the source of confusion: according to the value category taxonomy in C++17 and later, a prvalue is a recipe for constructing an object, and not an object itself. Consider the following code:

```
T foo() {
    return {};
}
T t = foo();
```

In C++14, the `return` statement and the initialization of `t` are two separate steps, although elision is permitted as an optimization. In the first step, the return object (*a.k.a.* "`foo()`") is copy-initialized from `{}`. In the second step, `t` is copy-initialized from that return object. Obviously, the first step occurs in the callee context and the second step in the caller context.

So in C++17, you might think that a similar two-step process occurs, only with the revised prvalue concept: namely, since `foo()` is a prvalue, you might think that the `return` statement simply creates a recipe (which may be conceptually represented as `[](void* p) { new (p) T{}; }`) and said recipe is created in the callee context, while the execution of that recipe to create `t` would occur in the caller context. If this were the case, then the actual call to the default constructor of `T` would occur in the caller's context and thus any exception thrown by it would not encounter the outer brace of the callee.

However, the standard has explicit language that denies this interpretation:

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization [...] from the operand.

That is, the initialization of `t` is done by the `return` statement itself. This implies that `t` is fully initialized before the callee's outermost block is actually left. For example, if there are any local variables in the callee that need to be destroyed, that actually happens after `t` has already been initialized (this behaviour is therefore potentially different from that of C++14). Just as it's clear that the destruction of such local variables occurs in the callee context (and therefore the search for a handler, if an exception were thereby thrown, would encounter the outermost block of `foo`), it's also clear that the initialization of `t` occurs in the callee context.

Answer (score -2):

Do it like this:

```
template <typename T> constexpr 
auto myfunc() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>)
{
    return T{};
}
```