# Where are exceptions thrown when arguments are passed by value

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, pass-by-value, noexcept

I have a type throwing when copied:

```
struct A { A(const A&) { throw 1; } };

void doit(A)
{
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    doit(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Is the exception thrown inside or outside of the function? Can I declare the function as noexcept?

Comment: Dup of [Constructor with by-value parameter & noexcept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628333/constructor-with-by-value-parameter-noexcept) and [Who manages the exception thrown by a copy constructor in parameters? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031634/who-manages-the-exception-thrown-by-a-copy-constructor-in-parameters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See C++17 [expr.call]/4

> ... The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of
>   the calling function. [ *Example:* The access of the constructor, conversion functions or destructor is checked at the point of call in the calling function. If a constructor or destructor for a function parameter throws an exception, the search for a handler starts in the scope of the calling function; in particular, if the function called has a *function-try-block* (Clause 18) with a handler that could handle the exception, this handler is not
>   considered. — *end example* ]

So the exception is, as you would put it, thrown "outside of the function". You can declare it `noexcept`.

Comment: For those who find this answer helpful. See also another question I asked a while ago about [copy-ellision and noexcept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957330/copy-elision-of-return-values-and-noexcept). It is related but not equal.